# Transform for child element by parent element tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I want transform child element rotate if parent element have class `open`. Example in css

```
ul li.open > a > .sidebar-collapse-icon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

How can I do it in tailwind?

Comment: can  you share your html part

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#group-hover

Answer (score 1):

As of Tailwind 3.1, this can be done with [arbitrary variants](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#using-arbitrary-variants):

Here is the generic syntax to use this feature:

```html
<div class="[&>*]:text-lg">
  <div>This element will have the `text-lg` class applied to it.</div>
  <div>So will this one!</div>
</div>
```

You can use generic CSS selectors to target child elements:

```html
<div class="[&>*:first-child]:text-lg">
  <div>This element will have the `text-lg` class applied to it.</div>
  <div>This element will be unchanged.</div>
</div>
```

You can also can target specific elements by class name:

```html
<div class="[&>*.make-me-red]:bg-red-500">
  <div>This element will be unchanged.</div>
  <div class="make-me-red">This element will have a red background.</div>
</div>
```

---

To answer this topic's question, this example will not be rotated since the parent element doesn't have the `open` class:

```html
<ul class="[&.open>*]:rotate-180">
  <li>I'm not upside-down yet...</li>
</ul>
```

Now, when we add the `open` class to the parent, the modifier class will be activated:

```html
<ul class="open [&.open>*]:rotate-180">
  <li>I'm upside-down now!</li>
</ul>
```

You can even target specific children with the relevant selectors:

```html
<ul class="open [&.open>*:first-child]:rotate-180">
  <li>I'm upside-down!</li>
  <li>I'm not upside down!</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find the exact solution on Tailwind documentation. So tried this hack (instead of open, use `group` class):

```html
<ul>
  <li class="group">
    <a>
      <span class="sidebar-collapse-icon group-only:-rotate-180"></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should control css through JavaScript. Tailwind CSS is not relevant by question. I work with her and love this lib.

For example if you use:

Vanilla (pure) JavaScript:

```
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    .container {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>

  <script>
    const el = document.querySelector('.container')
    if (el) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

React (Hooks):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

export default function MyComponent() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  if (!isOpen) {
    return null
  }

  return (<div className="some-tailwind-class"></div>)
}
```

Vue `if-show` directive:

```
<template>
  <div if-show="!isOpen" class="some-tailwind-class"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Vue `v-if` directive:

```
<template>
  <div if-show="!isOpen" class="some-tailwind-class"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```